# Visual Studio - How save *changes* to current customized window layout?

Tags: visual-studio, customization

Starting with Visual Studio 2015, there is a feature to save multiple [customized layouts of the windows (panes) of the IDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customizing-window-layouts-in-visual-studio).

"Save Window Layout" is the menu command to create a new one of these.
It asks for the name to save the layout as.

But now that I've created several layouts, I don't want to create a *new* one; I want to save an *updated* version of one of my layouts. I want that to *replace* the existing one, with the same hot key shortcut.

How do I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do "Save Window Layout".
When it asks for layout name, type in **exactly the same name as before**.
This results in message box:

> A layout named '...' already exists.
>   Do you want to replace it?

Answer [Yes].

(Tested in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, v.15.9.6.)

Comment: Perhaps this answer is obvious to many people, but before thinking to try same name, I spent time looking for a "Save" or "Update" option that would do this. It is also a minor annoyance to have to retype the name - the first dialog box that appears where type name could have made this easier by either: a) having a button to "Save updates to current layout", or b) starting with the current layout name filled in (and selected, so if start typing it goes away), and text explaining that if you use the same name again, you will get option to save over that one.